# Nodejs memory limit to 512 MB

Tags: node.js, v8

I'm trying to limit Nodejs process memory limit to 512 MB or less using node --max-old-space-size app.js but its not work for me.

I'm using node v7.10.0 and x64 processor

Comment: I think you need to specify a value for the option `--max_old_space_size`, for example `node --max_old_space_size=512 app.js`

Answer (score 2):

working fine with node `--max-old-space-size app.js` by mistake i was trying with `--max_old_space_size`(Underscore) this was wrong.